# ¿Cómo enviar un correo de respuesta automática de un formulario?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-hoja-de-cálculo, gmail, google-forms

estoy haciendo un codigo en Google Apps Script, lo que deseo que haga es que envíe un correo de respuesta automática cada vez que envíe una respuesta nueva de un formulario que tengo asociado a una hoja de  calculo, tengo este codigo pero cuando envio varias respuesta, se envía el correo, pero cada vez que alguien envíe una nueva respuesta vuelve a ejecutarse y vuelve a enviarse todos los correos que hay en la hoja de cálculo. Tengo el trigger, pero tengo ese problema.

Este es el codigo que estoy utilizando.

```
function myFunction() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var rows = sheet.getDataRange();
  var numRows = rows.getNumRows() - 1;
  var values= rows.getValues();

for(var i = 1; i<= numRows; i++){
  var email=values[i][2];
  var nombre=values[i][1];
  var archivo=values[i][3];
  var file;
  var adminEmail="CorreoDondeVaAllegarTodosLosRegistrados@correo.com";


GmailApp.sendEmail(email, "Correo de confirmacion", "Hola "+nombre+", gracias por haberte registrado");
GmailApp.sendEmail(adminEmail, "Nuevo usuario registrado", "Nuevo usuario registrado desde el formulario de bienestar: "+nombre+"\nEmail: "+email);
  } 

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Usando el objeto evento del form, recupera las respuestas de tu formulario para despues con ellas construir el mensaje y enviar el correo cada vez que se reciba una nueva respuesta, configura el trigger para que se ejecute al enviar el formulario.

```
function formSubmitReply(e) {

var timestamp =e.values[0];
var Respuesta1 =e.values[1];
var Respuesta2 =e.values[2];

var correo ="micorreo@ejemplo.com.mx";
var Asunto = "Mi asunto ";
var emailBody = "Se obtuvieron las siguintes respuestas"+ 
               "\n" +
               "\nPregunta1:"  + Respuesta1 + 
               "\nPregunta2:"  + Respuesta2 ;

MailApp.sendEmail(correo, Asunto, emailBody);                                
}
```

Comment: Hola, al colocar el evento en las lineas 3 al 5 se va la funcion de values.. y de una tira el error de no esta definido. Como soluciono eso? gracias de antemano.

Answer (score 0):

El problema ocurre porque tu script está recorriendo todos los datos.

Tienes varias alternativas

1. **Mejor opción** Usa [objeto evento](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events#form-submit) del activador "form submit" de la hoja cálculo como argumento de tu función y en lugar de usar getDataRange usa alguna de las propiedades de dicho objeto. Tal vez lo más sencillo sea usar la propiedad range pues haciendo esto serían mínimos los cambios que deberás realizar a tu código. En mi respuesta a [¿Cómo puedo probar una función disparadora en Google Apps Script](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/505/65) hay un ejemplo además que trata sobre cómo probar este tipo de funciones.
2. Agrega una columna para registrar el estado de enviado y una condición para hacer que el envío ocurra sólo para las filas que no tengan dicho estado. Esto podría causar problemas si tienes envíos de respuesta simultáneos o varios usuarios modificando la hoja de cálculo.