# ¿Como hacer que este script de google sheet funcione en varios rangos?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-hoja-de-cálculo

Tengo hecho un *script* de `google sheet` que me escribe la fecha de modificación de un rango concreto de celdas y ahora quiero hacer que detecte la celda que estoy modificando y detecte si esta dentro de unos rangos concretos.

Este es el *script* que tengo:

```
function onEdit(HoraModificacion){
  var DateCol = "K9";
  var curDate = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), "GMT+01:00", "hh:mm");
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Test2');
  var range = sheet.getRange('C11:K109');
  var rowIndex = range.getRowIndex();
  var colIndex = range.getColumnIndex();

  // May need to set up multiple ranges like this and check all ranges if
  // checked fields are not in adjacent cells
  var watchRange = { 
    top : 11,         // start row
    bottom : 109,     // end row
    left : 2,        // start col
    right : 12,        // end col
  };
  // Exit if we're out of range
  if (rowIndex < watchRange.top || rowIndex > watchRange.bottom) return;
  if (colIndex < watchRange.left || colIndex > watchRange.right) return;

  var currentValue = range.getValue();
  currentValue = currentValue.replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g,""); //"trim" kludge

  if (currentValue.length != 0){

    // Set a column to show last edit date
    SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange(DateCol).setValue(curDate);

  };
}
```

El problema es que no se como hacer para que detecte la celda que estoy modificando y a partir de esta detecte en que rango esta de unos previamente selecciona, tenia pensado hacer algo como lo de abajo, pero no me termina de salir. La finalidad de esto es tener una serie de rangos controlados, para saber cuando me los han modificado, cada rango tiene su propia celda para escribir la fecha de la modificación.

```
function onEdit(HoraModificacion){
    var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Test2');
    //Get the cell you are modifying to make a conditional for multiple range detect
    var activeCell = sheet.getActiveCell();
    //var activeRange = sheet.getActiveRange();
    var range1 = sheet.getRange('C11:K109');
    if ( activeCell == range1){
        var DateCol = "K9";
        var curDate = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), "GMT+01:00", "hh:mm");
        var rowIndex = range.getRowIndex();
        var colIndex = range.getColumnIndex();

        // May need to set up multiple ranges like this and check all ranges if
        // checked fields are not in adjacent cells
        var watchRange = { 
            top : 11,         // start row
            bottom : 109,     // end row
            left : 2,        // start col
            right : 12,        // end col
        };
        // Exit if we're out of range
        if (rowIndex < watchRange.top || rowIndex > watchRange.bottom) return;
        if (colIndex < watchRange.left || colIndex > watchRange.right) return;

        var currentValue = range.getValue();
        currentValue = currentValue.replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g,""); //"trim" kludge

        if (currentValue.length != 0){

            // Set a column to show last edit date
            SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange(DateCol).setValue(curDate);

        };
    }else if{
    //Check the other range
    return;
    };
}
```

Basandome en lo que me ha dicho Ruben he modificado mi script y ahora tengo esto:

```
function onEdit(e){
  var curDate = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), "GMT+01:00", "hh:mm");
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Test2');
  var colInicio = e.range.getColumn();
  var filaInicio = e.range.getRow();
  var ref = e.range.getA1Notation(); // Notación tipo A1 o A1:B2
  var range = e.getRange();
  var colIndex = colInicio.getColIndex();
  var rowIndex = filaInicio.getRowIndex();

  var watchRange1 = { 
    top : 11,         // start row
    bottom : 109,     // end row
    left : 3,        // start col
    right : 11,        // end col
  };

  var watchRange2 = { 
    top : 11,         // start row
    bottom : 109,     // end row
    left : 13,        // start col
    right : 21,        // end col
  };

  if(rowIndex >= watchRange1.top && rowIndex <= watchRange1.bottom && 
  colIndex >= watchRange1.left && colIndex <= watchRange1.rigth && 
  range.getValue() != 0){
    var DateCol1 = "K9";
    SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange(DateCol1).setValue(curDate);

 }else if (rowIndex >= watchRange2.top && rowIndex <= watchRange2.bottom && 
 colIndex >= watchRange2.left && colIndex <= watchRange2.rigth && 
 range.getValue() != 0){
    var DateCol2 = "U9";
    SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange(DateCol2).setValue(curDate);
 }else{
    //if test
    var DateCol1 = "K9";
    SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange(DateCol1).setValue("Fallo");
 }
}
```

Al intentar ejecutar este script me sale este error : No se puede leer la propiedad "range" de undefined. (línea 4, archivo "Dia1")

Sigo bastante atascado con el script

Detecto que el problema esta antes del if, pero no consigo solucionarlo.

Comment: por que a tu pregunta le pusiste cerrado?

Comment: eso no es correcto, si alguien te dió una respuesta útil; entonces ahora tu deber es aceptar dicha respuesta para indicar la solución como aceptada

Answer (score 1, accepted):

De la [revisión 5 de la pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/revisions/218357/5)

> Al intentar ejecutar este script me sale este error : No se puede leer la propiedad "range" de undefined. (línea 4, archivo "Dia1")

El error se debe a que estás ejecutando directamente el script, esto es, sin pasar un objeto evento, en este caso `e` es `undefined`. En [¿Cómo puedo probar una función disparadora en Google Apps Script](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/505/65) se explica cómo probar activadores simples.

Otro error potencial que pude observar a simple vista ocurre en la línea

```
var range = e.getRange();
```

Si `e` fuera el objeto evento, no sería un objeto de tipo Spreadsheet ni de tipo Sheet, en lugar de esta línea podrías usar

```
var range = e.range;
```

Sin embargo no le veo mucho sentido ahorrar dos caracteres, pero eso ya es cuestión de estilo.

Comment: De todas maneras no veo el fallo que hace que el script no funcione

Comment: @IvánMontero ¿Has revisado la transcripción de la ejecución? ¿Sabes cómo usar el depurador de código incluido en el editor de Scripts? Ambos se describen en https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/support/troubleshooting

Comment: He añadido esta linea
`var e = SpreadsheetApp.getCurrentCell().getValue();`
Pero me esta dando este error : TypeError: No se puede llamar al método "getColumn" de undefined.

Comment: @Iván Al agregar esa línea ya no cuentas con la propiedad range ni las otras del objeto evento. Pareciera que estás haciendo cambios sin ton ni son por lo que te sugiero intentar con una función onEdit más sencilla para que comprendas su funcionamiento, luego ir agregando más complejidad poco a poco.

Comment: La funcion onEdit sencilla es la primera que puse, ahora intento mejorarla para que funcione como quiero, podria crear varias veces la misma funcion, pero creo que la hoja de calculo de google no deja.

Answer (score 2):

---

NOTA: Respuesta correspondiente a la [revisión 3](https://es.stackoverflow.com/revisions/218357/3) de la pregunta. Para el error introducido en la [revisión 5](https://es.stackoverflow.com/revisions/218357/5) de la pregunta

> Al intentar ejecutar este script me sale este error : No se puede leer la propiedad "range" de undefined. (línea 4, archivo "Dia1")

véase mi [segunda respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/219030/65).

---

## Respuesta corta

Para detectar el rango que está siendo editado usa

```
function onEdit(e){
  var colInicio = e.range.columnStart; // Número de fila de la primera columna del rango editado
  var filaInicio = e.range.rowStart; // Número de fila de la primera celda del rango editado
  var ref = e.range.getA1Notation(); // Notación tipo A1 o A1:B2
}
```

## Repuesta ampliada

Lo primero a tener presente es que se puede editar más de una celda a la vez.

Considero muy inusual llamar `HoraModificacion` al parámetro de la función `onEdit` o de cualquier otro nombre reservado para funciones de activadores simples e incluso a funciones a ser llamadas por activadores instalables. Lo usual es usar `event` o `e`.

Al parámetro de la función onEdit le será asignado un objeto de evento que entre sus propiedades incluye el rango que fue editado. El nombre de esta propiedad es `range`. Puedes consultar el resto de las propiedades en https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events#edit

Cabe mencionar, que el objeto evento del activador "edit", además de las propiededades mencionadas en las documetnación incluye `columnStart` y `rowStart` que indican la columna y fila respectivamente de la primera celda del rango editado

Comment: Hola, siguiendo lo que me has pasado he intentado modificar mi script, pero este me esta dando un fallo con el range, que he comentado modificando mi pregunta.

Answer (score 0):

para detectar la celda puedes recurrir al evento mismo usando [onEdit(e)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events#top_of_page)
tal como lo refiere la ayuda oficial

en este ejemplo se revisa si la celda editada corresponde o esta dentro de las columnas 2 a la 6

```
function onEdit(e){
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var rango = e.range; 
if (SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getName() == "Hoja 2") {
  if (rango.getColumn() >= 1 && rango.getColumn() <= 6) {
    ss.toast("Documento Actualizado." + "\n\nRango:" + rango.getA1Notation() + "\n\ncon valor:" 
    + rango.getValue(),"Actualizar Fecha en el Calendario Comercial",15); 
  } 
 }
}
```

si adicionas el método "getRow()" al segundo **if** podrías conseguir verificar que este dentro del rango de filas que necesitas valorar.

espero te sea de utilidad