# Ayuda con script de Hoja de calculo de Google

Tags: google-apps-script, google-hoja-de-cálculo

Estoy intentando hacer un script para la hoja de calculo de google pero estoy atascado y no me funciona.

Mi intencion es hacer un script que detecte la celda que estoy modificando, para posteriormente, mirar si esta dentro de unos rangos concretos y dependiendo del rango, me escriba en una celda concreta la hora de modificación de dicho rango.

Este es el script que tengo hecho de momento:

```
function onEdit(e){
  var curDate = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), "GMT+01:00", "hh:mm");
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Test2');
  var range = e.range;
  //var colInicio = e.range.getColumn();
  //var colInicio = e.getColumn();
  //var filaInicio = e.range.getRow();
  //var filaInicio = e.getRow();
  //var activeRange = e.getActiveRange();
  //var ref = e.getA1Notation(); // Notation tipe A1 or A1:B2
  var ref = range.getA1Notation;
  var colIndex = ref.getColIndex;
  var rowIndex = ref.getRowIndex;

  var watchRange1 = { 
    top : 11,         // start row
    bottom : 109,     // end row
    left : 3,        // start col
    right : 11,        // end col
  };

  var watchRange2 = { 
    top : 11,         // start row
    bottom : 109,     // end row
    left : 13,        // start col
    right : 21,        // end col
  };

  if(rowIndex >= watchRange1.top && rowIndex <= watchRange1.bottom && 
  colIndex >= watchRange1.left && colIndex <= watchRange1.rigth && 
  e.getValue() != 0){

    var DateCol1 = "K9"; //Cell you want to have the date
    SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange(DateCol1).setValue(curDate); 
    //Write the date in the cell

  }else if (rowIndex >= watchRange2.top && rowIndex <= watchRange2.bottom && 
  colIndex >= watchRange2.left && colIndex <= watchRange2.rigth && 
  e.getValue() != 0){

    var DateCol2 = "U9"; //Cell you want to have the date
    SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange(DateCol2).setValue(curDate); 
    //Write the date in the cell

  }else{

    var DateCol1 = "K9";
    SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange(DateCol1).setValue("Fallo");

  };
}
```

Creo que el fallo esta antes del if, pero no consigo sulucionarlo.

Comment: Entre otros errores, uno es que te faltan los paréntesis en `var ref = range.getA1Notation;`

Comment: En una respuesta a tu pregunta anterior te había dejado el enlace a [¿Cómo puedo probar una función disparadora en Google Apps Scripts](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/505/65). Si no lo has hecho aún , revisa esa pregunta, estoy seguro que te será de mucha utilidad.

Comment: @Rubén justo ayer consegui solucionar este problema, ahora estoy intentando solucionar otro, gracias.

Comment: no le pongas cerrado a tu pregunta eso no es válido como te indique en tu otra publicación

Comment: Iván : Aquí esperamos que si el autor de la pregunta encontró una solución, la comparta. Cabe destacar que las buenas preguntas no se cierran, las que se cierran son las malas preguntas.

Comment: @Rubén, gracias, me respondere a mi mismo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Despues de estar investigando y preguntando he conseguido que mi script hiciera lo que yo quería, lo dejo por aquí por si alguien tiene una mejor solución.

```
function onEdit(e){
    var curDate = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), "GMT+01:00", "hh:mm");
    var range = e.range;
    var colIndex = range.getColumnIndex(); //Same as getColumn()
    var rowIndex = range.getRowIndex(); //Same as getRow()
    var DateCol1 = "K9"; //Cell you want to have the date
    var DateCol2 = "U9";

    if(e.range.getSheet().getName() === 'Test2'){

        var watchRange1 = { 
            top : 11,         // start row
            bottom : 109,     // end row
            left : 3,        // start col
            right : 11,        // end col
        };  
        var watchRange2 = { 
            top : 11,         // start row
            bottom : 109,     // end row
            left : 13,        // start col
            right : 21,        // end col
        };

        if(colIndex >= watchRange1.left && colIndex <= watchRange1.right && rowIndex 
        >= watchRange1.top && rowIndex <= watchRange1.bottom && e.Value != 0){

            SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange(DateCol1).setValue(curDate); 
            //Write the date in the cell

        }else if (colIndex >= watchRange2.left && colIndex <= watchRange2.right && 
        rowIndex >= watchRange2.top && rowIndex <= watchRange2.bottom && 
        e.Value != 0){

            SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange(DateCol2).setValue(curDate);

        };
    };
}
```

Imagino que habra una soloción para no tener que hacer 300 mil watchRange con sus respectivos if.

Comment: Podrías pasar los if a una función que utice como parámetro los watchRange