# Mi script solo funciona en mi usuario

Tags: google-apps-script, google-hoja-de-cálculo

Tengo un script en una hoja de calculo de google que funciona perfectamente pero solo con mi usuario, cuando otro usuario hace la accion que ejecuta el script, este no funciona aunque el usuario le de permiso en su cuenta, alguna solucion?

Dejo un enlace al ejemplo de la hoja de calculo que meciono:

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1y5H1x84tyt43HEhtescDmuL-cXPHhL8KzJ2MkT_3eZo/edit?usp=sharing

Dejo un ejemplo del codigo aqui:

```
function onEdit(e){
    var curDate = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), "GMT+01:00", "hh:mm");
    var range = e.range;
    var colIndex = range.getColumnIndex(); //Same as getColumn()
    var rowIndex = range.getRowIndex(); //Same as getRow()
    var DateCol1 = "K9"; //Cell you want to have the date
    var DateCol2 = "U9";
    if(e.range.getSheet().getName() === 'PARCMÒBIL'){
        var watchRange1 = {
            top : 11, // start row
            bottom : 109, // end row
            left : 3, // start col
            right : 11, // end col
        };
        var watchRange2 = {
            top : 11, // start row
            bottom : 109, // end row
            left : 13, // start col
            right : 21, // end col
        };
    if(colIndex >= watchRange1.left && colIndex <= watchRange1.right && 
    rowIndex >= watchRange1.top && rowIndex <= watchRange1.bottom && e.Value 
    != 0){

       SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange(DateCol1).setValue(curDate);
       //Write the date in the cell

    }else if (colIndex >= watchRange2.left && colIndex <= watchRange2.right 
    && rowIndex >= watchRange2.top && rowIndex <= watchRange2.bottom && 
    e.Value !=0){

      SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange(DateCol2).setValue(curDate);
    };};
}
```

Comment: Por lo que he estado viendo, parece que los scripts solo funcionan con el usuario que los crea

Comment: Quizás sea el caso de tu script pero no porque así sea en todos los casos. Además del ejemplo resumido de tu código agrega los pasos que has seguido para verificar que el problema se debe al código y no a un problema de cómo el otro usuario está usando tu hoja de cálculo. Si no lo has hecho aún, usa una segunda cuenta para reproducir el problema y agrega a tu código enunciados de registro (como `console.log(mensaje)`) para que puedas verificar que efectivamente se está llamando al script y que las condiciones están funcionando correctamente.

Comment: @Rubén El código funciona lla que lo he probado con mi usuario, pero cuando lo hace otro no funciona

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/88415/discussion-between-ruben-and-ivan-montero).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

He encontrado la solución a mi problema, y la verdad es que era una tonteria muy grande, el script si que estaba funcionando con los otros usuarios, el problema era que la casilla donde el script tenia que escribir esos usuarios la tenian protegida, al desproteger esa celda el script funciona perfectamente.

Conclusión: Los scripts de la hoja de calculo de google respetan las protecciones.

Comment: La conclusión no es del todo correcta. Lo que debes saber es que un activador simple como onEdit se ejecuta de forma anónima, es decir, no puede realizar cosas que requieran permisos, por el contrario, los activadores instalables se ejectuan con los permisos del usuario que los creo.

Answer (score 0):

Tu código tiene al menos un error

```
e.Value
```

debería ser

```
e.value
```

Lo anterior ocurre porque Google Apps Script es sensible a mayúsculas y minúsculas. El objeto evento tiene una propiedad `value`, no `Value`.

Para depurar tu código y encontrar este y posiblemente otros errores sigue las recomendaciones que se dan en [¿Cómo puedo probar una función disparadora en Google Apps Script](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/505/65)

Comment: Puede que lo copiara mal, pero no es el código por que a mí me funciona

Comment: @IvánMontero en es caso corrige el código en la pregunta.

Comment: @IvánMontero Revisé una copia que hice de la hoja de cálculo. En este está e.Value en varías líneas de código, así que no se trata de que lo hayas copiado mal en la pregunta.

Comment: Correcto, pero a mi me funciona con e.Value, por lo que no es tan sensible como parece

Comment: @IvánMontero El que el script haga algo no significa que funcione (entendiendo por ello que lo hace de forma correcta). e.Value retorna `undefined`, no el valor de la celda modificada.