# Como puedo llamar a una función en el Método OnOpen() de Google Apps Script?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-hoja-de-cálculo

Estoy haciendo un proyecto para una pequeña empresa de conectar su base de datos con google spreedsheet, he generado un pequeño script en el cual realizo una consulta y me la carga en el documento, pero si esta función la llamo desde el método onOpen() es decir cuando abro el documento, no se ejecuta. Creo que es por tema de permisos, pero no encuentro solución a este problema. Lo que quiero hacer es que cada vez que se abra el documento se actualizan los campos con la consulta seleccionada. Dejo aquí una captura de las funciones.

[image]
[image]

Comment: Bienvenido a SOes, siempre es mejor agregar el código en texto que en una imagen, ya que el enlace a la imagen se puede 'romper' y ademas el código en texto facilita que alguien pueda copiar y pegar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

onOpen es el nombre reservado la el activador simple que se ejecuta al abrir el contenedor (documento, hoja de cálculo, presentación, editor de formulario).

Los activadores simples como onOpen y onEdit se ejecutan prácticamente de forma anónima, por lo que no pueden ejecutar servicios que requieran autorización implícita. Las alternativas son utilizar un activador instalable o bien llamar esos servicios que requieren autorización usando OAuth.

Hace poco Google cambió la forma de crear los activadores instalables, ahora se crean desde https://script.google.com > *Proyecto* > Activadores. También puedes acceder esta página desde el IDE haciendo clic en el menú Editar > Activadores del Proyecto Activo. El botón Añadir activador se encuentra en la esquina inferior derecha y el enlace para hacer lo mismo en la parte inferior (dependiendo del tamaño de la ventana lo verás en el centro o más cerca de la derecha).

[image]

En mi opinión en casos como este lo más práctico es usar un activador instalable.

Relacionado

- [Cómo puedo probar una función disparadora en Google Apps Script](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/505/65)

Referencias

- https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/
- https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable