# OnEdit en AppsScript - modificar celda archivo diferente

Tags: google-apps-script, google-hoja-de-cálculo, google-apps-script-simple-triggers

En la funcion onEdit consigo el valor de la celda activa y modifico el valor de la celda continua. El problema es cuando quiero modificar la misma celda con el mismo nombre de hoja en un libro diferente. Esto último no funciona.

```
function onEdit(e){ 
  var archivo = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();

  var nombreHoja = archivo.getName(); var filaActiva = e.range.getRow();

  var valor = e.range.getValue();
  var colActiva = e.range.getColumn();
  var fondo = e.range.getBackground();
  // cambio en celda siguiente a la celda activa
  e.range.offset(0,1).setValue(valor).setBackground(fondo);
  
  // cambio el valor de la misma celda y la misma hoja en otro libro diferente
  var ss2 = SpreadsheetApp.openById("*** mi id de pagina ****");
  var sheet = ss2.getSheetByName(nombreHoja);
  sheet.getRange(filaActiva, colActiva).setValue(valor).setBackground(fondo);

}
```

Comment: ¿Te refieres a esto: `sheet.getRange(filaActiva, colActiva).setValue(valor).setBackground(fondo);` ? Revisa el registro de errores y dinos si muestra algún error. Por otra parte, no veo que estés modificando nada ahí.

Comment: Con el setValue (valor) pretendo modificar el valor de la celda de otro libro con el valor de la celda activa.

Comment: Ya. Pero ¿estás depurando algo? Puedes verificar el valor por ejemplo `Logger.log(valor);`

Comment: Error Exception: No tienes permiso para llamar a SpreadsheetApp.openById. Permisos necesarios: https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets
    at onEdit(Código:37:28)   . Pero no se donde tengo que añadirlo

Comment: ¿Eres el propietario de esa hoja? ¿Haz ligado el código Google Apps Script a algún proyecto de la consola de Google? Si no recuerdo mal, en el pasado tuve un problema parecido y tuve que compartir la hoja el email del proyecto (que se genera en la consola de Google).

Comment: Soy el propietario de las dos hojas. Me has pillado con lo de compartir el mail del proyecto en la consola de Google. No se donde mirar.

Comment: ¿Cuando ejecutas el código no te sale una ventana de autorización?

Comment: Google cambió hace un tiempo la forma de autorizar el uso de APIs desde GAS. Estoy buscando la doc oficial pero no la encuentro. [Aquí te explican los pasos que hay que dar](https://tanaikech.github.io/2019/07/05/linking-cloud-platform-project-to-google-apps-script-project/),  es un poco engorroso al principio, pero aprenderás a moverte por la Consola de Google y demás, cosa obligatoria hoy día si quieres sacar máximo provecho a cualquiera de sus APIs. En el enlace puede que haya imágenes no actualizadas, hace poco Google cambió la interfaz de GAS y también la de la Consola.

Comment: no puedo ejecutar el código manualmente porque me da error en e.range.

Comment: No entiendo a qué te refieres con *manualmente* ¿? Si quieres trabajar con las APIs de Google tienes que crear un Proyecto en Google Cloud Plataform, copiar el ID de ese proyecto y pegarlo en la configuración de tu Script. Si estás usando la última interfaz de GAS a la izquierda aparece la rueda de configuración. Y, en la Consola de Google, para ese proyecto, debes habilitar la API de Google Sheets, para que tenga permisos de escritura en tus Hojas de Google.

Comment: En informacion si que me sale:                                                               Ámbitos de OAuth del proyecto
1 ámbito solicitado
See, edit, create, and delete your spreadsheets in Google Drive https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets

Comment: Pero antes mencionabas que salía un error de permisos necesarios. Entonces pregunto, ¿cuando lanzas el script te sale una ventana de OAuth diciéndote que autorices los permisos o no? Si sale esa ventana tienes que autorizar para poder escribir en la Hoja.

Comment: He copiado los dos libros a dos libros nuevos y al ejecutar le he dado todos los permisos que me pedía, pero sigue sin funcionar por lo que creo que tendré que crear el proyecto en Google Cloud Plataform

Comment: Dicho brevemente tienes que: 1. Crear un proyecto en GCP; 2. Habilitar en el proyecto la API de Google Sheets; 3. Obtener el ID del proyecto y ponerlo en la configuración del Script (en la opción que encontrarás en la ruedita de Configuración, a la izquierda; 4.Activar en el Script la API de Google Sheets desde la opción Servicios, en el panel de la izquierda (nueva interfaz de Google Script). Cuando ejecutes por 1ª vez te pedirá consentimiento, deberás aceptar y ya debería funcionar. Si no funciona, te lo cuento en otro comentario ...

Comment: ... Si aún así da error de permisos, entonces ve de nuevo al proyecto de GCP, busca lo que se parece a una dirección de email, copiala y abre las Hojas, dale a compartir y pega eso parecido a una dirección de email dándole permiso de Editor. Con esos pasos debería funcionar. Esto último no estoy seguro de que sea obligatorio, yo lo tengo así porque he dado permisos para que la API escriba en la Hoja desde mi servidor web en PHP. Si no funciona observa los logs de error y dinos lo que muestra.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No se puede usar un activador simple para utilizar servicios que requieran autorización. En su lugar debes de usar un activador instalable.

NOTAS:

1. Usualmente no es conveniente utilizar un nombre reservado para una función a ser llamada por un activador instalable, así que si sería conveniente que cambies el nombre a tu función `onEdit`
2. Algunas funciones que requieren autorización podrían funcionar cuando el propietario de la hoja de cálculo es quien ejecuta el script y cuando el propietario y editores usan cuantas del G Suite / Google Workspace y son del mismo dominio

Relacionadas

- [Como puedo llamar a una función en el Método OnOpen() de Google Apps Script?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/245352/65)

Referencias

- https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers
- https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable

Comment: Hola Ruben! Perfecta tu respuesta, he cambiado el nombre a la función , añadido en servicios el Google Sheets y en activadores esta funcion "al editarse"

Comment: Gracias por confirmar que te ha sido útil mi respuesta. Por favor márcala como aceptada (haz clic en el ✔) Ref. [¿Qué debo hacer cuando alguien responde mi pregunta?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)