# funcion no trabaja con onOpen()

Tags: google-apps-script, google-hoja-de-cálculo

Estoy trabajando con Google App Script. Ya tengo el algoritmo hecho. Básicamente copia la columna de una hoja y la coloca en otra hoja. Todo perfecto.

aquí esta el codigo:

```
function onOpen(){
  
    runsies();
}



function runsies() {
 
  importRange(
    "1RiOmt0zeA5hDx5_Vo0FNL1pE7W5KwNErVMBkLmOZBM8",  //Source ID -  e.g.QBa3ID3EWbK3FNReNUn5nlJwQFQR6l91zODzZTd6SA"
    "NAMES_NODES!D:D", // Source Range - e.g. "Task List!A2:G"
    "NAMES_OF_NODES!A1") // Destination Range Start - e.g. "Sheet1!B3";
}
 

/**
* Imports range data from one Google Sheet to another.
* @param {string} sourceID - The id of the source Google Sheet.
* @param {string} sourceRange - The Sheet tab and range to copy.
* @param {string} destinationID - The id of the destination Google Sheet.
* @param {string} destinationRangeStart - The destintation location start cell as a sheet name and cell.
*/
function importRange(sourceID, sourceRange, destinationRangeStart){
 
  // Gather the source range values
  const sourceSS = SpreadsheetApp.openById(sourceID);
  const sourceRng = sourceSS.getRange(sourceRange)
  const sourceVals = sourceRng.getValues();
 
  // Get the destination sheet and cell location.
  const destinationSS = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  const destStartRange = destinationSS.getRange(destinationRangeStart);
  const destSheet = destStartRange.getSheet();
 
  // Clear previous entries.
  destSheet.clear();
 
  // Get the full data range to paste from start range.
  const destRange = destSheet.getRange(
      destStartRange.getRow(),
      destStartRange.getColumn(),
      sourceVals.length,
      sourceVals[0].length
    );
  
  // Paste in the values.
  destRange.setValues(sourceVals);
 
  SpreadsheetApp.flush();
}
```

Abro el editor de App Script , lo ejecuto y todo perfecto. Busca la columna de la otra Spreadsheet y lo copia en esta.

El problema es que quiero corra esa función apenas abra la hoja de google. Pero no lo hace. He intentado de todo, he buscado mucho por la WEB pero todos los ejemplos que obtengo con la función `onOpen()` son para hacer menu y cosas asi. Yo simplemente quiero que la función `runsies()` se ejecute al abrir, pero estoy sufriendo tratando de hacer que funcione.

Comment: Siendo estrictos, faltan detalles, por ejemplo, la página de ejecuciones debería indicar si la función fue llamada y si esta se completó o falló pero esto no se menciona.

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [Como puedo llamar a una función en el Método OnOpen() de Google Apps Script?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/245352/como-puedo-llamar-a-una-funci%c3%b3n-en-el-m%c3%a9todo-onopen-de-google-apps-script)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En lugar de usar el activador simple onOpen, intenta usando una activador instalable. Esto debido a que los activadores simples tienen varias limitaciones, por ejemplo, el tiempo de ejecución está limitado a 30 segundos, y no pueden ejecutar comandos que requieran autorización.

También toma en cuenta que los activadores sólo funcionan para el propietario y para los editores de la hoja de cálculo.

Comment: la limitacion de 30 segundos ya la habia escuchado y no la habia tomado en cuenta. Eso si es verdaderamete importante.  Cual podria ser el ejemplo de un activador instalable Ruben?

Comment: Muchisimas Gracias Ruben. Me meti en el reloj de app Script y simplemente funcionó.  Pero lo que no entiendo es porque cuando lo haces con codigo dura 30 segundos, pero haciendolo manual (metiendote en el reloj) si queda fijo. Simplemente no le veo sentido.

Comment: @NIN que bueno que encontraste la página de activadores instalables. En cuanto a las limitaciones de los activadores simples, eso es una decisión de Google. Desconozco si han compartido que los llevó a ello.

Comment: Muchísimas gracias Rubén. Ahora tengo un inconveniente con esa implentacion pero lo haré en otra pregunta a ver si entre los dos podemos solucionarlo.