# Establecer la última fila de una hoja cuando se están añadiendo de forma contigua filas desde un formulario

Tags: google-apps-script, google-hoja-de-cálculo, google-forms

Mi aplicación, a medida que llegan respuestas de un formulario ejecuta un script que realiza una serie de operaciones con la última fila de la hoja. El problema es que para cuando el script quiere calcular esa última fila....
 `var NumUltFila = sheet.getLastRow();`
han llegado otra u otras nuevas filas que hacen que la última fila ya no es la que yo deseaba capturar.
¿Cómo podría solventar este problema?

---

*Nota del editor: Del.post publicado como respuesta por el AP:*

Efecitvamente, uso un formulario para enviar respuestas a la hoja. El script tiene un activador que responde a la llegada de una respuesta a la hoja. También uso `range` para capturar la fila, pero el problema es al comienzo del script debo dar un tiempo para que se calculen algunos datos en la hoja (si no lo hago no funciona bien). Pues bien, en ese tiempo puede ser que llegue una nueva respuesta de formulario. Aunque yo bloquee la ejecución del script a otras instacias, mi script  va a capturar como última fila una que no es la que pretendía capturar, sino otra que llegó despues de iniciarse su ejecución. Por tanto la pregunta sería: cómo asegurarse cuando se ejecuta un script con un activador de respuesta de formulario y se intenta capturar la última fila con `range`, que  no estás capturando una fila posterior a la que desencadenó el activador?

```
function creayenviaparte() {
     //hago tiempo para que acabe CopyDown
  Utilities.sleep(30000);

   // Bloqueo a partir de aquí el script para que no pueda ejecutarse en paralelo esta parte del código
  var lock = LockService . getScriptLock ();   
   // Espere hasta 30 segundos para que finalicen otros procesos que utilizan este código
  lock.waitLock (30000);

  //abro la hoja
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();


  ss.setActiveSheet(ss.getSheetByName('nombre'));
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();




   // averigüo última fila 
  var NumUltFila = sheet.getLastRow();
```

Comment: Hola Juan, Bienvenido a StackOverflow en Español, mira [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) agrega el código que tienes hasta el momento y sí has intentado algo, para que sea más fácil ayudarte. Además te recomiendo hacer el [Recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para que entiendas más sobre el sitio y ganes tu primera medalla.

Comment: Juan: He copiado el texto de tu respuesta y pegado este en la pregunta, esto porque en este sitio las publicaciones de respuesta deben ser única y exclusivamente para responder la pregunta, además, es en la pregunta donde debe incluirse, de forma breve, toda la información necesaria para poder responderla adecuadamente.

Comment: ok, perdón y gracias

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dado que estas usando los formularios de Google y los has configurado para enviar las respuestas de forma automática a la hoja de cálculo vinculada, podrías tomar en cuenta que

1. la respuesta se inserta en la primera fila disponible luego del intervalo de datos, la cual se convierte, al menos momentáneamente, en la última fila.
2. el activador "on form submit" envía un objeto evento como argumento, para usarlo, tu función debe incluir una variable que lo reciba
3. el objeto evento incluye una propiedad range a la que se asigna el invervalo que ha recibido la respuesta.

Ejemplo:

```
/**
 * Función a ser llamada por un activador de hoja de cálculo "on form submit"
 *
 * @param {Object} e Objeto evento enviado por el activador "on form submit"
 * @param {string} e.authMode Un valor del enum ScriptApp.AuthMode 
 * @param {Object} e.namedValues Un objeto que contiene los nombres de las preguntas y valores enviados del formulario
 * @param {Range}  e.range Un objeto Range, representando la celda o intervalo de celdas que han sido editados
 * @param {string} e.triggerUid ID del activador que ha producido este evento
 * @param {Array}  e.values Un Array con valores en el mismo orden en el que aparecen en la hoja de cálculo
 */
function alRecibirUnaRespuesta(e){
   var ultimaFila = e.range.getLastRow();
   console.info('La última fila luego de recibir la respuesta del formulario es %s', ultimaFila);
}
```

Nota: Para depurar la función anterior, debe crearse una función que  llame la función que queremos depurar enviando un objeto evento con las características requeridas.

Relacionado

- [Cómo puedo probar una función disparadora (activador) en Google Apps Script](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/505/65)

Referencias

- [Events Objects | Google Apps Scripts](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events)
- [Class Range (getLastRow)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getlastrow)

Comment: Problema solucionado con tu ayuda. Muchas gracias por tu sabia lección.

Comment: @JuanRuizFernández Me alegra que te haya sido de utilidad mi respuesta. Si no lo has hecho aún, por favor lee https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Answer (score 0):

Efecitvamente, uso un formulario para enviar respuestas a la hoja. El script tiene un activador que responde a la llegada de una respuesta a la hoja. También uso `range` para capturar la fila, pero el problema es al comienzo del script debo dar un tiempo para que se calculen algunos datos en la hoja (si no lo hago no funciona bien). Pues bien, en ese tiempo puede ser que llegue una nueva respuesta de formulario. Aunque yo bloquee la ejecución del script a otras instacias, mi script  va a capturar como última fila una que no es la que pretendía capturar, sino otra que llegó despues de iniciarse su ejecución. Por tanto la pregunta sería: cómo asegurarse cuando se ejecuta un script con un activador de respuesta de formulario y se intenta capturar la última fila con `range`, que  no estás capturando una fila posterior a la que desencadenó el activador?

```
function creayenviaparte() {
     //hago tiempo para que acabe CopyDown
  Utilities.sleep(30000);

   // Bloqueo a partir de aquí el script para que no pueda ejecutarse en paralelo esta parte del código
  var lock = LockService . getScriptLock ();   
   // Espere hasta 30 segundos para que finalicen otros procesos que utilizan este código
  lock.waitLock (30000);

  //abro la hoja
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();


  ss.setActiveSheet(ss.getSheetByName('nombre'));
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();




   // averigüo última fila 
  var NumUltFila = sheet.getLastRow();
```