# Estoy enviando un mail cuando se cambien dos celdas pero cuando las modifico no se envía

Tags: google-apps-script, google-hoja-de-cálculo

Lo que quiero es que al modificar dos celdas una a una no las dos celdas al tiempo se me envié el correo, por ejemplo, tengo dos casillas de verificación y marco una y después la otra independiente si marco la segunda a los minutos o segundos me envié el correo. Gracias por la ayuda.

```
function mailNovedades() {
  const nHojaDatos = "Base Control Restrauraciones";
  const filasEncabezado = 1;
  const colCondicion = 19;
  const colCondicion2 = 21
  const valorCondicion = "VERDADERO";
  const valorCondicion2 = "VERDADERO";
  
  
  const celdaActiva = SpreadsheetApp.getCurrentCell();
  const valorActivo = celdaActiva.getValue();
  const valorActivo2 = celdaActiva.getValue();
  const colActiva = celdaActiva.getColumn();
  const colActiva2 = celdaActiva.getColumn();
  const filaActiva = celdaActiva.getRow();
  const nHojaActiva = celdaActiva.getSheet().getName();

  var email = celdaActiva.getSheet().getRange(filaActiva, 2).getValue();
  
 
  var plantilla = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("plantilla").getRange('A1').getValue();
  
  
  if (nHojaActiva == nHojaDatos &&
      filaActiva > filasEncabezado &&
      colActiva == colCondicion &&
      valorActivo == valorCondicion && 
      colActiva2 == colCondicion2 &&
      valorActivo2 == valorCondicion2)
      {
        
        var sucursal = celdaActiva.getSheet().getRange(filaActiva,3).getValue();
        var cupo = celdaActiva.getSheet().getRange(filaActiva,8).getValue();
        var constructora = celdaActiva.getSheet().getRange(filaActiva,14).getValue();
        var fecha = celdaActiva.getSheet().getRange(filaActiva,1).getValue();
        
        var mensaje = plantilla.replace("{{sucursal}}",sucursal)
        .replace("{{fecha}}",fecha)
        .replace("{{cupo}}",cupo)
        .replace("{{constructora}}",constructora)
        
        
        MailApp.sendEmail(email, "Notificación de actualización novedades", mensaje)
    
  }

}
```

Comment: Podrias adjuntar una foto de la planilla de hoja de calculo? porque creo que se puede simplificar el codigo @Diego

Answer (score 1):

Para que el correo se envíe de forma automática puedes usar los activadores de Google Apps Script. Hay de dos tipos, los simples que disparan una función que tenga uno de los nombres reservados, en este caso sería `onEdit` y los instalables que pueden llamar la función que especifiques, en este caso podrías usar el activador  editar (edit) o al cambiar (change). Los detalles en:

- https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers
- https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable

P.D.

Al usar el activador simples o instalable editar puedes ahorrarte varias líneas de código y además hacer tu script más eficiente si en lugar de leer uno a uno los datos de la celda activa sacas provecho del objeto evento editar ya que este include la propiedad `range` que tiene asignado el rango que fue editado y esta propiedad además tiene las propiedades `rowStart`, `rowEnd`, `columnStart` y `columnEnd`. Los detalles en:

- https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events

Relacionado

- [Cómo puedo probar una función disparadora (activador) en Google Apps Script](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/505/65)